# Update rows with duplicate values (in the same columns)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to update my table so that rows that share values (in the same columns) get tagged as such.

Example table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
  `id`  int NOT NULL ,
  `a`  varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
  `b`  varchar(10) NOT NULL , 
  `state`  tinyint NOT NULL , 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ;
```

I'd like to update "state" of every row that share values in the same column. So if row one has "a=AAAA" and row two has the same value for "a", both should get updated.

I tried this but it's too slow (not faster then doing it in Java using JDBC):

```
declare mycursor cursor for select id, a, b from mytable;
open mycursor;
repeat
   fetch mycursor into idid, aa, bb;
   update mytable set state=1 where (a=aa, b=bb)
until done end repeat;
close mycursor;
```

Any ideas to make this way better? I haven't done any decent SQL in years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to my question seems to be the following:

```
update mytable  as t1 inner join mytable as t2 on (t1.a=t2.a or t1.b = t2.b) and t1.id <> t2.id set t1.state=1;
```

Please say so if it is not (it seems to work, but it might do strange things) ;)

Answer (score 7):

Try first query to view rows with duplicates -

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t1
  JOIN (
    SELECT a, b FROM MyTable
      WHERE a = 'aa' AND b = 'bb' -- additional condition
      GROUP BY a, b
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2
  ON t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b
```

Try this one (based on first query) to update `status` field -

```
UPDATE MyTable t1
JOIN (
  SELECT a, b FROM MyTable
  WHERE a = 'aa' AND b = 'bb' -- additional condition
  GROUP BY a, b
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2
ON t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b
SET t1.state = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
update MyTable
set state = 1 
where id in (
select id 
from MyTable t1, MyTable t2 
where t1.id <> t2.id 
and t1.a = t2.a 
)
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause. Thank you for your effort, though!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a cursor for that, you can simply execute your update statement as you have it and all rows will be updated in one shot provided the condition holds true.

If I am missunderstanding your question and you do need to go through every record in that way, you can easily change the cursor for a simple while loop starting with min(Id) and ending with max(Id). The while loop should perform much faster than the cursor.